# How to get a property of a type when Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, parent

I have a type called "MyType" and my Pivot's ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection property called "DataSource" inside the "myFirstVM" ViewModel. Inside "MyType" i have the property Title. As you can see from my XAML the TextBlock is bound to MyProperty. How to make it return the current item Title?

So for example, If i am on the second PivotItem, I need the Title of the second item in the DataSource collection

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Pivot Name="myPivot"
           SelectedItem="{Binding myFirstVM.SelItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding myFirstVM.DataSource}"
           ItemTemplate="{Binding myFirstVM.OtherTemplate}">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.myFirstVM.MyProperty, ElementName=myPivot}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

**myFirstVM code:**

```
private ObservableCollection<MyType> _dataSource;
public ObservableCollection<MyType> DataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (this._dataSource == null)
        {
            this._dataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
        }
        return this._dataSource;
    }
    set { }
}

public string MyProperty 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (null != this.SelItem)
        {
            return this.SelItem.Title;
        }

        return "no title";
    } 
    set { }
}

private MyType _selItem;
public MyType SelItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _selItem = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("SelItem");
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<MyOtherType> OtherDataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (null != this.SelItem)
        {
            return this.SelItem.OtherCollection;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<MyOtherType>();
        }
    }
    set { }
}

private MyOtherType _selOtherItem;
public MyOtherType SelOtherItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selSegment;
    }
    set
    {
        _selSegment = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("SelOtherItem");
        RaisePropertyChanged("PartsDataSource");
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<MyThirdType> ThirdDataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (null != this.SelOtherItem)
        {
            return this.SelOtherItem.ThirdCollection;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<MyThirdType>();
        }
    }
    set { }
}
```

And these are my DataTemplates for the inner collections "OtherDataSource" and "ThirdDataSource", that are ListBoxes:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OtherTemplate">
    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding myFirstVM.OtherDataSource}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ThirdTemplate}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding myFirstVM.SelOtherItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ThirdTemplate">
    <ListBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding myFirstVM.ThirdDataSource}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FourthTemplate}">
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

EDIT: I updated the question with the full ViewModel, and the DataTemplates, as sugested by @olitee. The problem with this approach as you can see is that in the second, and third dataTemplate I have ListBoxes. I am using one ViewModel for all the things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a little extra work. Your ViewModel is not currently aware of which item is selected. You could create a new property called 'SelectedItem', and bind the Pivots' SelectedItem value.

Then you can access the Selected Item in code.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
   <Pivot Name="myPivot"
       Tag="{Binding}"
       SelectedItem="{Binding myFirstVM.SelectedItem}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding myFirstVM.DataSource}"
       ItemTemplate="{Binding myFirstVM.ViewDataTemplate}">
   <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.myFirstVM.MyProperty, ElementName=myPivot}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Then your VM would look something like:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyType> _dataSource;
public ObservableCollection<MyType> DataSource
{
    get
    {
        if (this._dataSource == null)
        {
            this._dataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
        }
        return this._dataSource;
    }
    set { }
}

public string MyProperty 
{ 
    get
    {
        if (this.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            return this.SelectedItem.Title;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    } 
}

private MyType _selectedItem;

public MyType SelectedItem
{ 
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    } 
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to fix up the text for presentation, and don't really require the SelectedItem in your VM, you could go with @Jehof's approach - but implement an IValueConvertor that performs the fix.

Comment: I can see, but _selectedItem is null and then crashes on MyProperty getter saying that Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Yes, _selectedItem can (and probably will) be null - particularly when your view is loading. You'll need to include a null check in your MyProperty getter. I've updated the sample code ...

Comment: I also did the null check, but it doesn't work. It does not crash, but it also doesnt work. Nothing shows in the header.

Comment: Which Pivot control are you using? Infragistics? DevExpress?

Comment: Ah, you're on Windows Phone? Does @Jehof's binding work, even though it's not the solution you want? Or does it fail to update? You may need to subscribe to the SelectionChanged event instead.

Comment: So, yes I made it work (see my answer). But this solution will probably only work with Pivot, where SelectedItem is changed every thime a selectionChanged event occures. But how to do the same trick when I have a ListBox (with templated items), instead of Pivot? I don't think it is possible

Comment: It should be possible. I've used that approach with the ListBox in Silverlight and WPF before - no problems.

Comment: But the problem with the ListBox is that I only need to display the items that are templated, so I won't select them and so this way the SelectedItem property will never change?

Comment: Any ideas how to perform this trick with a ListBox instead of a Pivot?

Comment: I'm a little confused - the items in your listbox won't be selected, but you want to know ... which one is selected? :) Could you clarify a little. What exactly do you mean by 'selection' in this case?

Comment: olitee, by using your technique, which is cool you can populate a Pivot with PivotItems, because you swipe through them and that way you select an item. Then SelectedItem is changed and you can update the collection within. But when using a ListBox this technique is useless, because ListBox is in front of you, and you don't need to select an item to perform collection update. Do you have any idea how to ace this problem?

Comment: @V.G. Sorry, I'm having some difficulty visualising exactly what you're trying to achieve. Could you update your question with some xaml that shows your listbox, and maybe even your item template?

Comment: I updated the question, but still cannot figure it out how to acheive the same effect as the Pivot with the inner ListBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Title, ElementName=myPivot}"/>
```

Bind the Text-Property to the SelectedItem property of the Pivot element. When the selected item of the Pivot changes the TextBlock should display the Title of the item.

Comment: Cool, but it binds directly to the Model, and I need to bind it to the ViewModel property wrapper, where I have to do some fixes the the value first.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right XAML implementation:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding myFirstVM.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and in the code behind instead of OnNotifyPropertyChanged the ViewModel needs to inherit ViewModelBase, part of MVVM Light then in the setter of SelectedItem property:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is when using ListBox control instead of Pivot the only needs to display items, without changing the selection, It will not work. With pivot, you swipe left/right and SelectedItem is changed, but not in the listBox.. Does anyone have an idea how to do it with another control, where you only need to show the items. How to iterate through all of them to force the binding?